# Validate a real date

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Is there some function that can validate a date in format aaaa/mm/gg (ccyy/mm/dd) returning `True` if it is valid or `False` otherwise? I mean about really valid date, not only to level to syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very fast, because the most simple errors are caught first.

```
function IsValidDate(const S: string): boolean;
var
  y, m, d: Integer;
const
  DAYS_OF_MONTH: array[1..12] of integer = (31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
  31, 30, 31);
begin
  result := false;
  if length(S) <> 10 then Exit;
  if (S[5] <> '/') or (S[8] <> '/') then Exit;
  if not TryStrToInt(Copy(S, 1, 4), y) then Exit;
  if not TryStrToInt(Copy(S, 6, 2), m) then Exit;
  if not InRange(m, 1, 12) then Exit;
  if not TryStrToInt(Copy(S, 9, 2), d) then Exit;
  if not InRange(d, 1, DAYS_OF_MONTH[m]) then Exit;
  if (not IsLeapYear(y)) and (m = 2) and (d = 29) then Exit;
  result := true;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, Andreas. :) This works (and so no downvote), but the asker is using XE2. The better answer is the one by @Arjen that uses `TFormatSettings`. I would have allowed the exception rather than throw it away by using `TryStrToDate` as Arjen did, though.

Comment: @Ken, thanks. And about the exception: depends on the circumstances.
Andreas, and NO downvote from me.

Comment: `StrToDate(S, Format)` approach in not way is XE2 specific, but isnt strict enough. Positive. And i think what real downvoter tries to frame someone.

Answer (score 7):

Is 'aaaa' year and 'gg' day?

```
var
  MyString: string;
  MyDate: TDateTime;
  settings: TFormatSettings;
begin
  settings.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy/mm/dd';
  settings.DateSeparator := '/';
  MyString := '2011/15/15';
  if TryStrToDateTime(MyString, MyDate, settings) then
    Label1.Caption := 'correct date'
  else
    Label1.Caption := 'incorrect';
end;
```

Comment: Note: "If S contains only two numbers, it is interpreted as a date (m/d or d/m) in the current year." So, it is possible to pass validation with not well-formed string. Also, time part will pass too. Also, function skips leading spaces, giving yet more false positives.

Comment: Only assigning two fields of the settings record might be dangerous. I would probably try to initialize it from the currently active settings first: settings := TFormatSettings.Create(GetUserDefaultLCID);

Answer (score 2):

Use the overloaded version of StrToDate() that has a TFormatSettings parameter. Then you can pass in the desired format string for parsing, and it will return a TDateTime after validating the parsed values.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do the same thing and ran across this old thread.  I ended up writing my own function and thought that I'd post it.  How about this?

```
function IsValidDate(const S: string): boolean;
 var TestDate : tdatetime;
begin
 Result := False;

 if (LastDelimiter('/',S) >= 4) 
 and 
 (Length(S)-LastDelimiter('/',S) >= 4) 
 then

  Result := TryStrToDate(S,TestDate);

 end;
```

First off, I check to see if the second delimiter (/) is at least out there far enough to represent both a day and a month (4th position).  I then force a 4 digit year on them with the next line.  Change this second test to >=2 for a two digit, but I just figure that it's not so bad to force a four digit year - it's only two more strokes.

Finally, I test with TryStrToDate().  If there is only one delimiter, or if it's not a valid date, it will be caught here.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could check if the year was within the last 10 years or something as well.  Just add:

```
Result := Result and (Now - TestDate < 3650);
```

Dave